# Fastest way to find the maximum minimum value of two 'connected' matrices

Tags: python, numpy, matrix, optimization, memory

I want to maximize the following function:

```
f(i, j, k) = min(A(i, j), B(j, k))
```

Where `A` and `B` are matrices and `i`, `j` and `k` are indices that range up to the respective dimensions of the matrices. I would like to find `(i, j, k)` such that `f(i, j, k)` is *maximized*. I am currently doing that as follows:

```py
import numpy as np
import itertools

shape_a = (100       , 150)
shape_b = (shape_a[1], 200)

A = np.random.rand(shape_a[0], shape_a[1])
B = np.random.rand(shape_b[0], shape_b[1])

# All the different i,j,k
combinations = itertools.product(np.arange(shape_a[0]), np.arange(shape_a[1]), np.arange(shape_b[1]))
combinations = np.asarray(list(combinations))

A_vals = A[combinations[:, 0], combinations[:, 1]]
B_vals = B[combinations[:, 1], combinations[:, 2]]

f = np.min([A_vals, B_vals], axis=0)

best_indices = combinations[np.argmax(f)]
print(best_indices)
```

```py
[ 49  14 136]
```

This is faster than iterating over all `(i, j, k)`, but a lot of (and most of the) time is spent constructing the `A_vals` and `B_vals` matrices. This is unfortunate, because they contain many many duplicate values as the same `i`, `j` and `k` appear multiple times. Is there a way to do this where (1) the speed of numpy's matrix computation can be preserved and (2) I don't have to construct the memory-intensive `A_vals` and `B_vals` arrays.

In other languages you could maybe construct the matrices so that they container pointers to `A` and `B`, but I do not see how to achieve this in Python.

Comment: Please consider selecting an answer to this question so it doesn't hand around the unanswered queue forever. This and many of your other questions which have perfectly good answers.

Comment: @MadPhysicist I will, probably tomorrow once I get a better look at it!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Perhaps you could re-evaluate how you look at the problem in context of what min and max actually do. Say you have the following concrete example:

```
>>> np.random.seed(1)
>>> print(A := np.random.randint(10, size=(4, 5)))
[[5 8 9 5 0]
 [0 1 7 6 9]
 [2 4 5 2 4]
 [2 4 7 7 9]]
>>> print(B := np.random.randint(10, size=(5, 3)))
[[1 7 0]
 [6 9 9]
 [7 6 9]
 [1 0 1]
 [8 8 3]]
```

You are looking for a pair of numbers in `A` and `B` such that the column in `A` is the same as the row of `B`, and the you get the maximum smaller number.

For any set of numbers, the largest pairwise minimum happens when you take the two largest numbers. You are therefore looking for the max in each column of `A`, row of `B`, the minimum of those pairs, and then the maximum of that. Here is a relatively simple formulation of the solution:

```
candidate_i = A.argmax(axis=0)
candidate_k = B.argmax(axis=1)
j = np.minimum(A[candidate_i, np.arange(A.shape[1])], B[np.arange(B.shape[0]), candidate_k]).argmax()

i = candidate_i[j]
k = candidate_k[j]
```

And indeed, you see that

```
>>> i, j, k
(0, 2, 2)
>>> A[i, j]
9
>>> B[j, k]
9
```

If there are collisions, `argmax` will always pick the first option.

Comment: Thank you! One question: what if there are three connected matrices, i.e. `f(i,j,k) = min(A(i,j),B(j,k),C(i,k))`, does similar logic still apply?

Comment: The maximum three-mininum is still going to occur when you look at the three largest numbers. Your 3-case is a bit different, so if this answer doesn't help you build the required intuition, feel free to ask another question. You seem to have a good grasp on the necessary level of detail to clearly and precisely describe your problem

Comment: done, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69461798/fastest-way-to-find-the-maximum-minimum-value-of-three-connected-matrices. I struggled to apply the same approach since `i` and `k` are no longer 'free'.

Answer (score 0):

Your values `i,j,k` are determined by the index of the maximum value from the set `{A,B}`. You can simply use `np.argmax()`.

```
if np.max(A) < np.max(B):
    ind = np.unravel_index(np.argmax(A),A.shape)
else:
    ind = np.unravel_index(np.argmax(B),B.shape)
```

It will return only two values, either `i,j` if `max({A,B}) = max({A})` or `j,k` if `max({A,B}) = max({B})`. But if for example you get `i,j` then `k` can be any value that fit the shape of the array `B`, so select randomly one of this value.

If you also need to maximize the other value then:

```
if np.max(A) < np.max(B):
    ind = np.unravel_index(np.argmax(A),A.shape)
    ind = ind + (np.argmax(B[ind[1],:]),)
    
else:
    ind = np.unravel_index(np.argmax(B),B.shape)
    ind = (np.argmax(A[:,ind[0]]),) + ind
```

Comment: Your method gives `A[ind]` definitely not maximized for the example I generated. Could you work out the details of what you are proposing? I think I'm missing something.

Comment: This doesn't seem to account for the fact that the column/row index has to be common to both

Comment: @MadPhysicist It does, but It will only work if there is one and only one maximum value in the set {A,B} as in the OP's example

Comment: And for my first example, OP's said that he want to maximize `min(A(i, j), B(j, k))` so a value that is either in A or in B but not both according to that there is at least `A.shape[0]` or `B.shape[1]` possible result.

Comment: My understanding is that for a given `j`, he wants to find the maximum from each matrix, which guarantees the largest minimum for the pair. So what matters is not the maximum value in a given matrix, but the maximum in the other matrix in the corresponding row/column

Comment: @obchardon Sorry I think you misunderstood the problem. For example, `A=np.array([[8, 0, 7],[0, 2, 0]])` and `B=np.array([[0, 0, 0, 1], [9, 0, 0, 0], [0, 3, 0, 0]])` (I put zeros for easy reading). Your answer will look for max value in `A`,`8`. It's index in A is `(0,0)`... then it looks for max value in `B[0]`, then `f=1` and `(i,j,k)=(0,0,3)`. However, the correct answer is `f=3` and `(i,j,k)=(0,2,1)`. Imho, we should not look for global maximum in this case.