# Fastest way to find the maximum minimum value of three 'connected' matrices

Tags: python, numpy, matrix, optimization, memory

The answer for two matrices was given in this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69451946/fastest-way-to-find-the-maximum-minimum-value-of-two-connected-matrices/69452326?noredirect=1#comment122764945_69452326), but I'm not sure how to apply this logic to three pairwise connected matrices since there are no 'free' indices. I want to maximize the following function:

```
f(i, j, k) = min(A(i, j), B(j, k), C(i,k))
```

Where `A`, `B` and `C` are matrices and `i`, `j` and `k` are indices that range up to the respective dimensions of the matrices. I would like to find `(i, j, k)` such that `f(i, j, k)` is maximized. I am currently doing that as follows:

```py
import numpy as np
import itertools

I = 100
J = 150
K = 200

A = np.random.rand(I, J)
B = np.random.rand(J, K)
C = np.random.rand(I, K)

# All the different i,j,k
combinations = itertools.product(np.arange(I), np.arange(J), np.arange(K))
combinations = np.asarray(list(combinations))

A_vals = A[combinations[:,0], combinations[:,1]]
B_vals = B[combinations[:,1], combinations[:,2]]
C_vals = C[combinations[:,0], combinations[:,2]]

f = np.min([A_vals,B_vals,C_vals],axis=0)

best_indices = combinations[np.argmax(f)]
print(best_indices)
```

`[ 49  14 136]`

This is faster than iterating over all `(i, j, k)`, but a lot of (and most of the) time is spent constructing the `_vals` matrices. This is unfortunate, because they contain many many duplicate values as the same `i`, `j` and `k` appear multiple times. Is there a way to do this where (1) the speed of numpy's matrix computation can be preserved and (2) I don't have to construct the memory-intensive `_vals` matrices.

In other languages you could maybe construct the matrices so that they contain pointers to `A`, `B` and `C`, but I do not see how to achieve this in Python.

**Edit:** see a follow-up question for more indices [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69476527/fastest-way-to-find-the-maximum-minimum-value-of-connected-matrices)

Comment: did you try `numba` and iterating over matrices? compile it on small matrices example and timeit on bigger ones

Comment: @dankal444 I tried, but a lot of time is spent on the itertools which cannot be converted by `numba`. I will try to combine it with the answer below though!

Comment: yes, itertools are not needed at all, just use three `for` functions inside numba decorated function, each for i, j and k

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We can either brute force it using `numpy` broadcasting or try a bit of smart branch cutting:

```
import numpy as np

def bf(A,B,C):
    I,J = A.shape
    J,K = B.shape
    return np.unravel_index((np.minimum(np.minimum(A[:,:,None],C[:,None,:]),B[None,:,:])).argmax(),(I,J,K))

def cut(A,B,C):
    gmx = min(A.min(),B.min(),C.min())
    I,J = A.shape
    J,K = B.shape
    Y,X = np.unravel_index(A.argsort(axis=None)[::-1],A.shape)
    for y,x in zip(Y,X):
        if A[y,x] <= gmx:
            return gamx
        curr = np.minimum(B[x,:],C[y,:])
        camx = curr.argmax()
        cmx = curr[camx]
        if cmx >= A[y,x]:
            return y,x,camx
        if gmx < cmx:
            gmx = cmx
            gamx = y,x,camx
    return gamx
            
from timeit import timeit

I = 100
J = 150
K = 200

for rep in range(4):
    print("trial",rep+1)
    A = np.random.rand(I, J)
    B = np.random.rand(J, K)
    C = np.random.rand(I, K)

    print("results identical",cut(A,B,C)==bf(A,B,C))
    print("brute force",timeit(lambda:bf(A,B,C),number=2)*500,"ms")
    print("branch cut",timeit(lambda:cut(A,B,C),number=10)*100,"ms")
```

It turns out that at the given sizes branch cutting is well worth it:

```
trial 1
results identical True
brute force 169.74265850149095 ms
branch cut 1.951422297861427 ms
trial 2
results identical True
brute force 180.37619898677804 ms
branch cut 2.1000938024371862 ms
trial 3
results identical True
brute force 181.6371419990901 ms
branch cut 1.999850495485589 ms
trial 4
results identical True
brute force 217.75578951928765 ms
branch cut 1.5871295996475965 ms
```

How does the branch cutting work?

We pick one array (A, say) and sort it from largest to smallest. We then go through the array one by one comparing each value to the appropriate values from the other arrays and keeping track of the running maximum of minima. As soon as the maximum is no smaller than the remaining values in A we are done. As this will typically happen rather soonish we get a huge saving.

Comment: Thank you, this is impressive! Is there a way to make this more general? So let's say we don't have `f(i,j,k)` but we have `f(i,j,k,l)` with 6 pairwise matrices (`A(i,j), B(i,k), C(i,l), D(j,k), E(j,l) F(k,l)`). Can the cutting function be generalized?

Comment: There probably is but not off the top of my head. You could try some recursive scheme, I suppose. This is complicated enough to warrant a new question IMO.

Comment: and can the bruteforce unravel method be generalized? I tried so but have not succeeded so far

Comment: You have to construct the indices (like `[:,None,None,:]`). They have to be tuples and you have to use `slice(None)` for `:`. TO get all the patterns you need you can use `itertools.combinations` or `np.triu_indices`.

Comment: Thank you again, I have made the brute force technique work for arbitrary indices. I have posted a follow-up question for arbitrary number of indices here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69476527/fastest-way-to-find-the-maximum-minimum-value-of-connected-matrices

Comment: (and the reason for the follow-up is that the brute force method allocates lots of memory and kills the machine when 5+ indices are used)

Answer (score 1):

Instead of using itertools, you can "build" the combinations with repeats and tiles:

```
A_=np.repeat(A.reshape((-1,1)),K,axis=0).T
B_=np.tile(B.reshape((-1,1)),(I,1)).T
C_=np.tile(C,J).reshape((-1,1)).T
```

And passing them to np.min:

```
print((t:=np.argmax(np.min([A_,B_,C_],axis=0)) , t//(K*J),(t//K)%J, t%K,))
```

With timeit 10 repetitions of your code takes around 18 seconds and with numpy only about 1 second.

Comment: Thank you, is there a way to scale this? So let's say we don't have `f(i,j,k)` but we have `f(i,j,k,l)` with 6 pairwise matrices. Would it require more complex repeats and tiles?

Answer (score 1):

Building upon [great answer of loopy walt](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69467059/4601890)  - you can get slight speed-up (~20%) by using numba:

```
import numba
@numba.jit(nopython=True)
def find_gamx(A, B, C, X, Y, gmx):
    gamx = (0, 0, 0)
    for y, x in zip(Y, X):
        if A[y, x] <= gmx:
            return gamx
        curr = np.minimum(B[x, :], C[y, :])
        camx = curr.argmax()
        cmx = curr[camx]
        if cmx >= A[y, x]:
            return y, x, camx
        if gmx < cmx:
            gmx = cmx
            gamx = y, x, camx
    return gamx


def cut_numba(A, B, C):
    gmx = min(A.min(), B.min(), C.min())
    I, J = A.shape
    J, K = B.shape
    Y, X = np.unravel_index(A.argsort(axis=None)[::-1], A.shape)

    gamx = find_gamx(A, B, C, X, Y, gmx)
    return gamx

from timeit import timeit

I = 100
J = 150
K = 200

for rep in range(40):
    print("trial", rep + 1)
    A = np.random.rand(I, J)
    B = np.random.rand(J, K)
    C = np.random.rand(I, K)

    print("results identical", cut(A, B, C) == bf(A, B, C))
    print("results identical", cut_numba(A, B, C) == bf(A, B, C))
    print("brute force", timeit(lambda: bf(A, B, C), number=2) * 500, "ms")
    print("branch cut", timeit(lambda: cut(A, B, C), number=10) * 100, "ms")
    print("branch cut_numba", timeit(lambda: cut_numba(A, B, C), number=10) * 100, "ms")
```

```
trial 1
results identical True
results identical True
brute force 38.774325 ms
branch cut 1.7196750999999955 ms
branch cut_numba 1.3950291999999864 ms
trial 2
results identical True
results identical True
brute force 38.77167049999996 ms
branch cut 1.8655760999999993 ms
branch cut_numba 1.4977325999999902 ms
trial 3
results identical True
results identical True
brute force 39.69611449999999 ms
branch cut 1.8876490000000024 ms
branch cut_numba 1.421615300000001 ms
trial 4
results identical True
results identical True
brute force 44.338816499999936 ms
branch cut 1.614051399999994 ms
branch cut_numba 1.3842962000000014 ms
```