# How to create a matrix of multipliers based on given dimension and order? Sort of like combination, example given in description

Tags: python, numpy

I have a number given as dimension and order, where dimension = 2 and order = 3. I want to know what's the best way to create this matrix :
[[0, 0], [0, 1], [0,2], [0,3], ..., [3, 0], [3, 1], [3, 2], [3, 3]]

Basically the shape of this matrix is ((order + 1) ** dimension, dimension), and I want to have all the possible combinations for each order. Both dimension and order values could be different, so I'm looking for a generalizable solution that can construct this matrix based on the dimension and order passed in.

Comment: What have you tried? I think two simple nested for loops would work.

Comment: Hi, thank you, that was my initial thought as well. I just wanted to ask whether there's a clever way of doing using numpy functions

Comment: Actually, I couldn't do it with simple loop. Because if the dimension increases, you have to ensure that the same combination doesn't appear. For example if dimension was 3, I would want something like this : [[0, 0, 1], [0, 1, 0], [0, 2, 0], [0, 0, 2], [0, 1, 2], [0, 2, 1] ..., and it goes on. Basically for every order from 0 to 3 (inclusive), I would have to have all the choose 2 out of [0, 1, 2, 3] possibilities.

Comment: Check this question, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69461798/fastest-way-to-find-the-maximum-minimum-value-of-three-connected-matrices/69465234#69465234 it has multiple answers for order = 3. The user then asked a separate question for the general case but i don't remember what happended to it. The tldr is to use itertools.product but for bigger dimensions you run into speed/memory problems real fast.

Comment: `itertools` has a `combinations` and `product`.  `numpy` has `meshgrid`, `mgrid`, `indices, `ndindex` etc.  Read some docs, and read linked answers.